# How to convert monthly time-series in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I am working on a monthly-based time-series data set:

```
> head(data, n=10)
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   Month               Inflation
   <dttm>                  <dbl>
 1 1979-01-01 00:00:00    0.0258
 2 1979-02-01 00:00:00    0.0234
 3 1979-03-01 00:00:00    0.0055
 4 1979-04-01 00:00:00    0.0302
 5 1979-05-01 00:00:00    0.0305
 6 1979-06-01 00:00:00    0.0232
 7 1979-07-01 00:00:00    0.025 
 8 1979-08-01 00:00:00    0.0234
 9 1979-09-01 00:00:00    0.0074
10 1979-10-01 00:00:00    0.0089
```

Although it appears that the data is yet to be recognized as a time-series data as it shows the following structure:

```
> str(data)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   479 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Month    : POSIXct, format: "1979-01-01" "1979-02-01" "1979-03-01" "1979-04-01" ...
 $ Inflation: num  0.0258 0.0234 0.0055 0.0302 0.0305 0.0232 0.025 0.0234 0.0074 0.0089 ...
```

When I tried to convert it using xts function, it gave me this error:

```
> inflation <- xts(data[,-1], order.by=as.Date(data[,1], "%m/%d/%Y"))
Error in as.Date.default(data[, 1], "%m/%d/%Y") : 
  do not know how to convert 'data[, 1]' to class “Date”
```

Please help me with the most appropriate way of data conversion.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
# You have something like:
data <- data.frame(
  Month = as.Date(as.Date("1979-01-01"):as.Date("2000-01-01"), origin="1970-01-01"),
  Inflation = rnorm(7671)) # same number of obs
```

## Create TS

choose start and end dates appropriatelly

```
tseries <- ts(data$Inflation, start = c(1979,1), end = c(2000,1), frequency = 12)
plot(tseries)
```

Comment: Do you mind to explain the "rnorm(7671)" bit? I assumed it's the number of observations/rows. Yet when I put the number of observations as 479, it gave me error: Error in data.frame(Month = as.Date(as.Date("1979-01-01"):as.Date("2018-11-01"),  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 14550, 479

Comment: It is the number of observations. You don't need to create the data frame at all. That was just to demonstrate your data situation. Simply take the variable with the inflation and specify the start and end date as well as the frequency. In the example I created monthly data from Jan. 1979 to Jan. 2000.

Comment: OK it worked perfectly once I run the ts() function right away. I should have skipped the data frame creation as you said. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @[Muhammad Akbar Almuttaqin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10775717/muhammad-akbar-almuttaqin), please accept this answer (click the tick mark beside it), if you find this solved your problem... then easier for others to find if it's solved or not later on.